# Can Set-QADUser set all properties?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm using the Quest commandlets for a very simple and straightforward update but it's not working. No errors, it just fails to change the value:

```
Set-QADUser ttest -ObjectAttributes @{office="ABQ"}
```

Can't get much simpler - what am I doing wrong? both of these work fine:

```
Set-QADUser ttest -objectAttributes @{otherTelephone=@('555-34-67','555-34-68')}
Set-QADUser ttest -objectAttributes @{otherTelephone=''}
```

but this does not:

```
Set-QADUser ttest -objectAttributes @{extensionattribute2="test"}
```

Comment: using dsquery with dsmod probably is a little more fullproof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the actual name of the attribute in Active Directory. The "office" attribute doesn't exist. I believe you want `physicalDeliveryOfficeName`. Be sure to -IncludeAllProperties when querying a user object to get the extensionAttribute2.

Use [ADSIEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28WS.10%29.aspx) to get a list of AD user properties.

Comment: Strange... I tried physicaldeliveryofficename (incorrect case but correct property) and that worked. I guess "Office" is a property that Quest adds to the object after the fact. extensionattribute2 works also (but you have to use -includeallproperties switch to see it when you query the user object). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Set-QADUser ttest -objectAttributes @{extensionattribute2='"test"'}
```

it worked for me.